# In matplot format_coord only need to display x y coordinates of plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, `format_coord` displays x and y co-ordinates if mouse hovers anywhere over the graph canvas.  How should I restrict display to show only coordinates only when mouse pointer is above curve?

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

class MyAxes(Axes):
    name = 'MyAxes'
    def format_coord(self, x, y):

        # Massage your data here -- good place for scalar multiplication
        return 'time=%s Damped oscillation=%s' % (x, y)
from matplotlib.projections import projection_registry
projection_registry.register(MyAxes)    

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)

y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x2)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1, projection="MyAxes")
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'ko-')
plt.title('Oscillation')
plt.ylabel('Oscillation')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @ali_m I have Added the code do you have any idea?